# What are the Difference between cElementtree and ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml

I know a little of dom, and would like to learn about ElementTree. Python 2.6 has a somewhat older implementation of ElementTree, but still usable. However, it looks like it comes with two different classes: xml.etree.ElementTree and xml.etree.cElementTree. Would someone please be so kind to enlighten me with their differences? Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, you may find lxml.etree interesting; while a 3rd-party module, this is a superset of the ElementTree specification, and includes useful features such as real XPath support.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is the same library (same API, same features) but ElementTree is implemented in Python and cElementTree is implemented in C.

If you can, use the C implementation because it is optimized for fast parsing and low memory use, and is 15-20 times faster than the Python implementation.

Use the Python version if you are in a limited environment (C library loading not allowed).

Comment: There are some subtle differences. In cElementTree, the `findtext` method did not have a `default` parameter (seen with Python 2.7.13). This can be easily replaced with `findtext("...") or "defaultValue"`, though.

Comment: I think the main, arguably the only, reason for not using cElementTree is when the binaries are not available for a given platform (chipset/os combination). For example, ElementTree may work just fine out of the box on a niche platform that supports python but cElementTree binaries may not be available for that platform. Some of this is alluded to [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-binary-extensions/#disadvantages).

Answer (score 22):

But now they are the same thing [as of Python 3.3](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/a72a98f24a19928e31dcc4cab2cd2ad0f1846e11), in github source code [cElementTree](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/xml/etree/cElementTree.py)

> # cElementTree.py
>
> from xml.etree.ElementTree import *

it is just for backward compatibility

Answer (score 20):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html:

> Changed in version 3.3: This module will use a fast implementation whenever available. The xml.etree.cElementTree module is deprecated.

So for Python 3.3 and higher just use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

Comment: This should clear up the confusion. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

From http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm:

> The cElementTree module is a C implementation of the ElementTree API, optimized for fast parsing and low memory use. On typical documents, cElementTree is 15-20 times faster than the Python version of ElementTree, and uses 2-5 times less memory

Answer (score 5):

ElementTree is  implemented in python while cElementTree is implemented in C.  Thus cElementTree will be faster, but also not available where you don't have access to C, such as in Jython or IronPython or on Google App Engine.

Functionally, they should be equivalent.

Comment: Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html.  "A C implementation of this API is available as xml.etree.cElementTree.
"