# ElementTree / cElementTree difference?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree, celementtree

I have a small xml-parsing python snippet that works with ElementTree, but not with cElementTree. Why is that?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(sys.stdin)
```

this raises the exception:

```
cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

when its called like this

```
echo "<a><b>c</b></a>" | ./xmltest.py
```

EDIT: I just noticed that the snippet works in python 2.7.2, but not in python 3.2.2 or 3.1.4, any idea why?

**Update:** It seems to be fixed in python 3.3

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418262/python-unicode-and-elementtree-parse) SO question? Is  your case a unicode problem?

Comment: while that seems to be related, I don't think I can "reopen" sys.stdin with utf8 encoding, right?

Comment: is it a similar question with 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351694/what-are-the-difference-between-celementtree-and-elementtree?rq=1

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into the bug recently documented in [Issue 14246](http://bugs.python.org/issue14246).  Until it is fixed, one workaround for Python 3 is to change `sys.stdin` to be a `byte` stream rather than a `string` stream:

```
import sys
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

sys.stdin = sys.stdin.detach()
tree = ET.parse(sys.stdin)
```