# Python's xml.etree.ElementTree.parse more than 10 times slower than command line's xmllint

Tags: python, performance, elementtree, xmllint

I'm converting a Shell script to Python and I'm seeing a great performance downgrade due to the following line change.

Shell: `xmllint -noout XML_FILE_PATH 2> error_output`
Python: `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(XML_FILE_PATH)`

I'm suppossing they're just doing the same job, a parsing of the XML.

What other alternatives would I have in Python to avoid this performance loss?

Comment: If you use `cElementTree` instead of `ElementTree`, does it make a difference? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351694/what-are-the-difference-between-celementtree-and-elementtree.

Comment: @mzjn Wow! That's a bit of a boost. First tests (user time in seconds): xmllint 8, cElementTree 16, ElementTree 83. Many thanks!

Comment: You might also want to try [lxml](http://lxml.de), which is similar to ElementTree. lxml is based on the same C library as xmllint (libxml2).